# Showing the metric $\rho=\frac{d}{d+1} $ induces the same toplogy as $d$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to show that given a metric space $\left(X,d\right)$ the metric $\rho=\frac{d}{d+1}$  on $X$ induces the same topology on $X$ as $d$. It suffices to show that any open ball in $\left(X,d\right)$ is open in $\left(X,\rho\right)$ and vice versa. 
What I'm stuck on is finding a $\delta>0$  such that given $y\in B_{d}\left(x,\varepsilon\right)$ I will get $y\in B_{\rho}\left(y,\delta\right)\subseteq B_{d}\left(x,\varepsilon\right)$. This will give me that every open ball in $ \left(X,d\right)$ is open in $\left(X,\rho\right)$
 .

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Another way using the lemma that "if $X$ has a metric $d$, then the topology induced by $d$ is the coarsest topology relative to which the function $d$ is continuous" can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665772/how-to-complete-this-proof-to-show-that-the-metric-dx-y-dx-y-1-dx). The lemma is from the exercise 3 of section 20 of Munkres's Topology (2nd edition).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that for any metric $\rho$, we have *always* that $\rho\geq 0$, so that $$\frac{\rho}{1+\rho}\leq  \rho$$

so one direction is immediate. On the other hand, this tells us that given $\epsilon$ and $\rho(x,y)<\varepsilon $; we will have to take $\frac{\rho}{1+\rho}$ much smaller to get it inside the ball.  We want $$\frac{\rho(x,y)}{1+\rho(x,y)}<\delta$$ to imply that $$\rho(x,y)<\epsilon$$ Since all is positive

$$\begin{align}
   \frac{{\rho (x,y)}}{{1 + \rho (x,y)}} <& \delta \\
   \rho (x,y) <& \delta  + \delta \rho (x,y)  \\ 
   \left( {1 - \delta } \right)\rho (x,y) <& \delta   \\
   \rho (x,y) <& \frac{\delta }{{1 - \delta }} \end{align}$$

so $$\frac{{\rho (x,y)}}{{1 + \rho (x,y)}} < \delta\implies \rho (x,y) < \frac{\delta }{{1 - \delta }}$$

The inverse of $x\mapsto \frac{x}{1-x}$ is $x \mapsto \frac{x}{{1 + x}}$ so if we take $\delta  = \frac{\varepsilon }{{1 + \varepsilon }}$ we will have$$\frac{{\rho (x,y)}}{{1 + \rho (x,y)}} < \delta  \Rightarrow \rho (x,y) < \varepsilon $$ as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Try $\delta=\varepsilon/(1+\varepsilon)$.

Comment: +1, but it would be nice to explain how to get to that.