# Is $d'$ a distance? Does it define the same topology on $M$ as $d$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. Define the following function $d'(x,y):=\dfrac{d(x,y)}{d(x,y)+1}$ for every $x,y$ in $M$.
Is $d'$ a distance? Does it define the same topology on $M$ as $d$?
I didn't think $d'$ was a distance as $d'(x,y)$ could be less than $0$, of because the $x $ and $y$ are in $M$ does that mean that they have to be positive? Also not sure how to prove that the topology is the same?
Thanks

Comment: How could $d'(x,y)$ be less than $0$ unless $d(x,y)$ committed the same faux pas?

Comment: $\rm{Duplicate}^7$. But where...?

Comment: @julian [Duplicates. Duplicates everywhere.](http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120721175027/meme/es/images/2/2f/X,_X_Everywhere.jpg)

Comment: @skullpatrol What...?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I'll show this to my nephew. That's his favorite movie.

Answer (score 3):

I will let you prove by yourself that $$d'(x,y)\geq 0$$ $$d'(x,y)=0\iff x=y$$ $$d'(x,y)=d'(y,x)$$
Remember that $$d(x,y)\geq 0$$ $$d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$$ $$d(x,y)=d(y,x)$$

See what this implies for $d'=\frac{d}{1+d}$. Observe, for example, that $$\displaylines{
  0 \leqslant d(x,y) \cr 
  1 \leqslant d(x,y) + 1 \cr 
  1 \geqslant \frac{1}{{d(x,y) + 1}} \geqslant 0 \cr 
  d(x,y) \geqslant \frac{{d(x,y)}}{{d(x,y) + 1}} \geqslant 0 \cr} $$

The only bothersome property is the triangle inequality. To sort this out, we look at the function $f(x)=\dfrac x{1+x}$. It is increasing for positive values, so $x\leq y+z\implies f(x)\leq f(y+z)$. You should now prove that $$f(z+w)\leq f(z)+f(w)$$ and see that we obtain $d'$ by applying $f$ to $d$. You will have to show that for positive values, 
$$\frac{{z + w}}{{1 + z + w}} \leqslant \frac{z}{{1 + z}} + \frac{w}{{1 + w}}$$
is true.
To prove it generates the same topology, refer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361331/showing-the-metric-rho-fracdd1-induces-the-same-toplogy-as-d).